# Docker run binding container pip site-packages for peristant pip installs

Tags: docker

I am trying to bind my pip site-packages docker container directory to my host computer, but on my host computer the directory is empty.

```sh
docker run -d \
    -p 8080:8080 \
    --name "ml-workspace" \
    -v "/${PWD}:/workspace" \
    --mount type=bind,source=/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages,target=/workspace/cache/site-packages \
    --env AUTHENTICATE_VIA_JUPYTER="password" \
    --shm-size 512m \
    --restart always \
    dagshub/ml-workspace:latest
```

Also, I am trying to bind the vs studio extensions directory `--mount type=bind,source=/root/.vscode/extensions,target=/workspace/cache/extensions`, but docker doesn't seem to like `.` in the path.

Comment: Bind mounts always go in the other direction: you're mounting the (empty) host directory over the container contents.

Comment: When mounting the otherway, it seems to be correctly mounting but the pip installations seem to not be working.  The container seems to be restarting from failed installs:
`2020-10-30T20:36:19.074486916Z ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psutil'`